# How can I get use an element's innerText in an IF statement in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm trying to write some javascript such that when a user clicks on a tab titled 'New Tab', the context of the web page disappears. Nothing is happening, and I'm not sure why. My best guess is that the text of the parent element isn't being recognized. I could really use some help! I've been working on this for days. Below is the code for the tabs. Everything works up until the IF statement.

```
$("#content_tabs a").click(function () {
    $("#content_tabs li").removeClass("on");
    $(this).parent().addClass("on");
    if (($(this).parent().text()) == 'New Tab') {
        $("#context").hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `#context`? share the DOM structure

Comment: Can't really help you without seeing the DOM structure. Can you at least post the html for the list these tabs are in?

Comment: In what sense does the code not work at the if statement? It evaluates to false when you think it should be true? It throws an exception? Stops executing?

What is the value you get by inserting `alert($(this).parent().text())`?

Comment: I am working on this page within OpenText(otherwise known as Reddot)CMS. That's why this is so difficult. I'm not really able to share the DOM, however, here is the page I am working on: http://www.thomsonlinear.com/website/com/eng/products/linear_guides/linear_bearings/super_ball_bushings.php

Comment: Actually, Thank you dgvid for the 'alert' suggestion. I believe I have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without your markup it's difficult to say, but rather than rely on a specific element structure, you could replace this:

```
if (($(this).parent().text()) == 'New Tab') {
```

With:

```
if (($(this).closest("li").text()) == 'New Tab') {
```

Will go ascend the structure until it finds your nearest li tag.